# Walk through all tree nodes?

Tags: treesitter

I'm using `py-tree-sitter` and this code to walk the entire node tree in sequence (code is from this github issue: https://github.com/tree-sitter/py-tree-sitter/issues/33#issuecomment-864557166):

```py
def traverse_tree(tree: Tree):
    cursor = tree.walk()

    reached_root = False
    while reached_root == False:
        yield cursor.node

        if cursor.goto_first_child():
            continue

        if cursor.goto_next_sibling():
            continue

        retracing = True
        while retracing:
            if not cursor.goto_parent():
                retracing = False
                reached_root = True

            if cursor.goto_next_sibling():
                retracing = False

for node in traverse_tree(tree.root_node):
  print(node)
```

I'm using this code for syntax highlighting and this method does not give empty tokens like `whitespace` and `newline` which are not part of another `AST` token.

Is this the correct way to get all the nodes in the tree?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution is to use recursion. For example, since tree-sitter does not support query syntax for missing nodes yet, one possible solution to still get them:

```py
missing_nodes = []
def traverse_tree(node: Node):
   for n in node.children:
      if n.is_missing: missing_nodes.append(n)
      traverse_tree(n)
        
traverse_tree(tree.root_node)
```